# Audit with Excel files only log the first event

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, audit, audit-logging

I have activated the audit in SharePoint 2010 on the "View" event for my list items.

It is perfectly working with word files, however, with excel files, the audit only contains the first time the file has been viewed.

Does anybody have the same problem?